# How to change view of specific item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

Assuming that I have adapter with list of items and view for each item contains textview. How to access this item's textview and for instance change it's color.
I can do this by adding a click listener to each item and doing that change of text color when item is clicked. But is there a way to achieve this in other way ?

In my ViewHolder I got:

```
val info: TextView = view.find(R.id.info_item)
```

And a method:

```
fun bindItems(listItem: List<String>) {

                info.text = "Name: ${listItem[0]}"}
```

PS. I know how to change color of text view :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onBindViewHolder` you could do something like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(if(position%2==0) 0xffff0000.toInt() else 0xff00ff00.toInt())
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code , i have tried it and it is working :

```
private var row_index: Int = -1

itemView.txtContactAddress.setOnClickListener({
                row_index = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            })

if (row_index == position) {
                    itemView.txtContactAddress.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                } else {
                    itemView.txtContactAddress.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try following;

- create a class that was extended RecyclerView.ViewHolder at the same time implemented View.OnClickListener. (e.g MyViewHolder)
- override constructor if you think it is necessary
- override onClick function for click handling.
- call change View method from onClick function.
- return an instance for MyViewHolder from overrided onCreateView at adapter class.
- bind new ViewHolder.

Ps: don't forget change type parameter for adapter. (RecyclerView.Adapter)